# Get audio file size without export

Tags: ios, iphone, mpmediaitem, mpmediapickercontroller

i'm developing an app that export audio file stored in the iPod library, but i should verify the file size before export and upload (server has a fixed max upload size):

- i know that after exporting file, the size will not be the same: is there any method to estimate the new size ?
- main question : can i know the original file size before export (using MPMediaItem or something else), so i can tell user that this file can't be uploaded (the export can take a while).
  thanks.

Comment: your deployment target from ios 6 or 5

Comment: I have exactly the same question. estimatedOutputFileLength returns 0 in my case. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tested but AVAssetExportSession can help you with this.

```
MPMediaItem *curItem = musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem;

NSURL *url = [curItem valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];

AVURLAsset *songAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL: url options:nil];

AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset: songAsset
                                   presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];
```

exporter.estimatedOutputFileLength will give you size in bytes.

Comment: Yes it work thanks :), but we need to add a timeRange to the exporter :

    AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset: songAsset presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];

    CMTime half = CMTimeMultiplyByFloat64(exporter.asset.duration, 1);

    exporter.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, half);

    long long size = exporter.estimatedOutputFileLength;

Comment: can't give you the +50 ! the link doesn't seem to work, how should i do ?

Comment: Which link are you asking about?

Comment: You cannot get the estimatedOutputFileLength with AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough and you also need timeRange if using a different preset

Comment: I have exactly the same question. estimatedOutputFileLength returns 0 in my case. Any ideas ? I am using swift 4

Comment: The documentation says this returns 0 when the export preset is `AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough`, and it's deprecated in iOS 13

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure, but i think you could use:

```
MPMediaItem *item = [[collection items] objectAtIndex:0];
NSURL *url = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSLog(@"length %d",[data length]);
```

Regards,

Mariano

Comment: iOS 6, is there a difference ?