# How to know the audio file size from MPMediaPickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, alassetslibrary, mpmediapickercontroller

MPMediaPickerController can pick a MPMediaItem and use it to play music or export it to somewhere. I can get the duration of audio file but I can't find a way to know what the size of its. How can I get file size from audio file from assets-library? Thank you.

NSFileManager only can handle file in sandbox. It can not help for assets-library.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684800/get-audio-file-size-without-export ?

Comment: This solution save me. Thanks for Larme's help.

Comment: only duration of the song  ?